# Change where the header starts from in a fancyhdr header

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

I have a question that may seem basic, but I have searched for a similar situation without success. My issue is that I want the header to start from the bottom line and extend all the way to the top, instead of starting from the top and extending downwards. I am looking for a specific solution that does not require trial and error with different values. I have attached an MWE and an image of how the header currently appears, and how I want it to appear. Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[spanish,10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=3.00cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\hbadness = 1500


\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[L]{  \footnotesize
                Título del libro, Capítulo x1, pp. x2 - x3.\\
                ISBN: 978-607-9394-XX-X., 2023.}    
                
\fancyfoot[C]{\normalsize\thepage}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\centering}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\begin{center}
\fontsize{18}{21.6} \selectfont
Some good title for an article
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `\smash` a `[b]`ottom-aligned `tabular`, which will allow it to expand vertically without causing a warning.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[L]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
  Header title \\
  Header subtitle
\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  Some good title for an article
\end{center}

\end{document}
```